# What do you call a statue that is built to commemorate a person?

Tags: single-word-requests

Example:

> They built him a [...] to commemorate his achievements and
>   contributions to society.

Comment: Well, a "monument" is something built to commemorate or honor some person or event or whatever, but it's not necessarily a statue.  "Memorial" generally honors a person or group of people but similarly is not necessary a statue.

Comment: Eg, in Washington DC are the "Washington Monument", an obelisk honoring George Washington, and the "Lincoln Memorial", a pavilion containing a statue of the sitting Abraham Lincoln.

Comment: (And I hear those British guys have one or two monuments/memorials as well.)

Comment: A *memorial* commemorates someone who is dead (or a group of people of whom at least some are dead).

Comment: I'm having trouble with the **They built him a [...]** part of your question. The implication is that the object was presented and/or given **to him personally**, rather than being erected as a public commemoration or celebration of his achievements. This would be unusual — normally, when a living person's achievements are celebrated, it takes the form of a certificate, award or prize, or if it is a public monument, it may even be unveiled at a ceremony in which the honoree is present; but it is not normally constructed or erected **for** the person in question, nor is it **given** to them.

Comment: Yeah, to have a memorial (or a monument) you usually have to die first.

Comment: Well, some leaders are egotistical enough to have statues built in their honor while they are still alive (Saddam Hussein comes to mind). But these are not "memorials".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually you'd call it a *monument*.

Answer (score 1):

Monuments and memorials usually do not depict the person, unlike a statue.

I would write:

> They built a statue of him to commemorate his achievements and contributions to society.

or:

> They built a memorial to him to commemorate his achievements and contributions to society.

Comment: Exactly. Call it a statue if it's a statue, and a monument or memorial if it's not.

Answer (score 0):

If they're dead and it's at the site of their burial, it may also be called a tomb effigy or a [gisant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tomb_effigy).